# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to inject some values into a `SQL` table but it's not recognising one of the columns.

**php code**:

```
$db = get_PDO();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO presidents(name, year, vice_president) "
         . "VALUES (:name, :year, :vice_president);";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $params = array("name" => $names[$i],
                  "year" => $year[$i],
                  "vice_president" => $vice_president[$i],);
  $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

`$names`, `$year`, and `$vice_president` are arrays

**sql code**:

```
CREATE TABLE presidents(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(255),
   year INT,
   vice_president VARCHAR(255),
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vice_president' in 'field list'

Comment: i guess you have some typo issue, Because error not able to find your column , perhaps you miss-spell

Comment: You can see the code though, there are no typos in any of the "vice_president"s

Comment: you need to bind param check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples)